# CakePHP themed with robots.txt

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I have a CakePHP application that uses themed views, css and images. Now I need to have themed robots.txt as well.

Naturally I put a robots.txt file in every theme folder `/View/Themed/Theme/webroot/robots.txt`, but only the one in the `app/webroot` gets displayed. Usually themed files (img,css,js,ctp) will overwrite the "default" files.

**Is there a way to have different robots.txt files?**

note: before I used to have something like this in the htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bla.website.de$
RewriteRule robots.txt bla.robots.txt [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo.website.de$
RewriteRule robots.txt foo.robots.txt [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.website.de$
RewriteRule robots.txt noindex.robots.txt [L]
```

But this will get out of hand very fast.

Comment: It is supposed to be a static or a dynamically generated file? Why is the mod_rewrite solution not appropriate?

Comment: It can/should be a static file.
I would have to add 100 or more of these cases and it should be possible with theming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Themes don't work like that

> Usually themed files (img,css,js,ctp) will overwrite the "default" files.

Actually, that's not the case. CakePHP can only handle requests that reach the php code, if there is a static file matching the path in the way, that will get served directly by the webserver, as that's what [the default rewrite rules](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/webroot/.htaccess) implement.

When using a theme CakePHP will *change* the requested url i.e.:

> `app/Plugin/DebugKit/webroot/js/my_file.js` becomes `app/webroot/debug_kit/js/my_file.js`
>
> `app/View/Themed/Navy/webroot/css/navy.css` becomes `app/webroot/theme/Navy/css/navy.css`

So it is not that the response for assets (`/css/somefile.css`) is modified, an entirely different request (`/using_this_theme/css/somefile.css`) is made when using a theme.

This is, in fact, something you're expected to take advantage of, by putting or linking your theme assets directly in the webroot as [serving files via php is slower than not invoking php](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/themes.html#increasing-performance-of-plugin-and-theme-assets).

### Use a route and a controller action, not rewrite rules

Since you have a multiple-domain-points-at-one-application setup (implied) and want a single url (`/robots.txt`) to return *different* content it's not possible with the [default rewrite rules](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/webroot/.htaccess) to make the url point at a static file<sup>1</sup>. To make the contents of `/robots.txt` dynamic, simply delete the file in `webroot/robots.txt` and add a route and controller action to handle serving the content based on the theme that's relevant to the request.

<sup>1</sup> *Obviously it is possible to do it by changing rewrite rules, but that means added complexity, and prevents the response being configurable (using a different theme -> instant change of content). You could consider generating your rewrite rules programatically though*

Comment: I don't need the dynamic part.
I was hoping that this would work with theming and a static robots.txt file for each case.

Comment: So you are saying, that I should go with a route to a Controller or stick to the htaccess changes?